# Which common database library will rack up the least cost (e.g. from memory and cpu usage) on Google Cloud Run and similar services?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, redis, google-cloud-run

I want to make a CRUD API (create-read-update-delete) by which users can interact with a key-value store database. It'll be hosted on Cloud Run (e.g. [see this example](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/building-flask-api-with-cloud-firestore-and-deploying-to-cloud-run)) or a similar service, running all day to serve requests.

All data will have a short TTL (time-to-live) around 1 minute, and keys and values will just be short strings. Furthermore, speed, security, redundancy etc. aren't concerns (within reason).

In this case, which common database backend will be the cheapest in terms of its CPU and memory usage? I was thinking of using Redis, but I worried that it might be unnecessarily CPU/memory intensive over say SQLite, PostgresQL, etc..

Or is it the case that basically all these database libraries will have similar CPU/memory usage?

Edit:

Keys are 256-bit numbers, and values are <140-character strings. Every minute, a user requests to write/read from at most 100 of these, and let's just say there's 100k users.

Comment: These question is too broad and opinion based. You can't "properly" compare those databases on cpu/memory without knowing the data model, queries, traffic, size(rows etc).

Comment: Keys are 256-bit numbers, and values are <140-character strings. Every minute, a user requests to write/read from at most 100 of these, and let's just say there's 100k users. Does that narrow it down enough? I'd just like a somewhat broad/rough answer, since I don't even have the faintest clue what's right.

Answer (score 1):

Redis would do fine for this kind of use cases. RDBMs would also do the work but from what you explained, you don't need relational database for this since your data is key/value. Redis is super fast for this case and if you make a good data modeling you may reduce the memory usage.

Since your requirements are key/value and the keys/values have reasonable sizes, you may get the advantage of Redis hashes. In addition to that; you don't need a persistent storage, you may use `EXPIRE` to manage your memory usage easily. Redis's [benchmark tool](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) may help you to benchmark for both strings and hashes to decide which one uses less memory.

Couple of hours ago, I answered a question for reducing memory usage of Redis by using hashes over strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62974526/2188922), it may give some insight.